# What GPIO port should I use?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I am trying to execute this python script on a raspberry pi but I get an error pertaining to the port.
My code is

```
import neopixel
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
pixels = neopixel.NeoPixel(GPIO.D5, n= 30)
pixels[1] = (255, 0, 0)
```

this all works fine except I get an error in the GPIO library

```
AttributeError: module 'RPi.GPIO' has no attribute 'D5'
```

D5 is the data port I am using. Is this accurate or should I use the input power or the ground instead? Should I use another port entirely for this?
TIA

Comment: It is not a matter of changing the port number.  That particular attribute isn't in the GPIO module.  You may find that others aren't either.  See what attributes are in GPIO, perhaps using `dir(GPIO)` or reading the source.

Answer (score 1):

`GPIO` doesn't define pin names (instead you set them up directly, e.g. `GPIO.setup(5, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)` etc.)

**You probably mean `board.D5` instead.**

That library (`board`) is part of [CircuitPython](https://circuitpython.readthedocs.io/en/6.0.x/README.html), same as `neopixel`.

See an example [here](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Learning_System_Guides/blob/master/CircuitPython_Essentials/CircuitPython_NeoPixel_RGBW.py).